# Generate XML file in Sql Server in a different way

Tags: sql-server, xml, split

I have created two tables Employer and ReportPage.

The EmployerId is the common field for the two tables.
I want to generate the XML from the tables. I write some Queries and execute.

The Query is Here:

```
select e.EmployerName as EmployerName, 
       e.EmployerId as EmployerId, (
select
      rp.EmployerId as EmployerId,
      rp.PageNumber as PageNumber, 
      rp.Title as Title, 
      rp.Score as Score
       from ReportPage rp  where rp.EmployerId = e.EmployerId
       FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS)
       from Employer e where EmployerId = 09340 FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, root
      ;
```

It gives the output XML like this:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8' standalone = 'no'?>
    <root>
 <e>
    <EmployerName>Company, Inc.</EmployerName>
    <EmployerId>09340</GroupNumber>
      <rp>
          <EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
          <Title>Executive Summary</Title>    
          <Score>67</Score>
      </rp>  
 </e>   
 <e>
    <EmployerName>Company, Inc.</EmployerName>
    <EmployerId>09340</GroupNumber>
      <rp>
          <EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
          <Title>Executive Summary</Title>    
          <Score>75</Score>
      </rp>  
 </e>    
 <e>
    <EmployerName>Company, Inc.</EmployerName>
    <EmployerId>09340</GroupNumber>
      <rp>
          <EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
          <Title>Executive Summary</Title>    
          <Score>80</Score>
      </rp>  
 </e>
    </root>
```

But I expected this form of XML output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8' standalone = 'no'?>
    <root>
       <e>
          <EmployerName>Company, Inc.</EmployerName>
          <EmployerId>09340</GroupNumber>
       </e>
      <rp>
<EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
          <Title>Executive Summary</Title>    
          <Score>67</Score>
      </rp>     
      <rp>
<EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
          <Title>Common</Title>   
          <Score>75</Score>
      </rp>     
      <rp>
<EmployerId>09340</EmployerId>
          <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
          <Title>Physical</Title>     
          <Score>80</Score>
      </rp>   
    </root>
```

Could any help me that? I have tried for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: How is the ReportPage table related to the Employer table? I can't see any connection between them in your XML example. What are the fields in each table?

Comment: Could you possibly show us diagram of your database, those two tables?

Comment: Hi Matt Jones, now i connect the tables using the EmployerId

Comment: Providing a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your database structure and some sample data would be very helpful. The keywords you'll need to use are [for xml path](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20for%20xml%20path). What did you try already?

Comment: Hi xmojmr, I just posted a improved Question. I think it better help to understand my need. Can you help me...

Comment: See my answer below. If it works for you, then use instructions from [Help Center > Asking > What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have lost your reputation points because since the beginning your question was very unclear and did not show any research effort. Next time try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see also [Meta Stack Exchange: How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). Thanking by voting is considered enough on this site. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying instructions from article "[belle’s sql musings: SQLXML: How to Join Multiple XML Snippets (using query() and UNION ALL)](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/04/04/sqlxml-how-to-join-multiple-xml-snippets-using-query-and-union-all)" on your problem gave me this code:

```
DECLARE @EmployerId VARCHAR(5) = '09340'

DECLARE @eQuery XML
DECLARE @rpQuery XML

SET @eQuery = (
  SELECT
    e.EmployerName AS EmployerName, 
    e.EmployerId AS EmployerId
  FROM
    Employer e
  WHERE
    EmployerId = @EmployerId
  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT
)

SET @rpQuery = (
  SELECT
    rp.PageNumber AS PageNumber, 
    rp.Title AS Title, 
    rp.Score AS Score
  FROM
    ReportPage rp
  WHERE
    rp.EmployerId = @EmployerId
  ORDER BY
    rp.PageNumber
  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT
)

SELECT
  @eQuery.query('//e')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  @rpQuery.query('//rp')
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('root'), TYPE
```

You can check the results online in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e95b5/7/0

---

Disclaimer: I'm no `T-SQL` expert, the query probably might be improved a bit and some magic keywords thrown away, I just hacked it together using Google without knowing what it really does (and why)